# Java xmldsig DigestValue ( jsr105Provider apche, oracl )

Tags: java, apache, web-services, xml-dsig

I am trying to implement a java webservice client. Soap message is signed (internal detached signing).

I have an example of valid message that validates as correctly signed.

When I try my code, the message is not correctly signed. Trying to track the problem, i realized that the problem (or my mistake) is related to the generation of  for one of the references in .

In the example that works correctly, I can 'verify' how the DigestValue is created:

```
<ds:Reference URI="#Id-4889213">
<ds:Transforms>
  <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
    <ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList=""/>
  </ds:Transform>
</ds:Transforms>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
<ds:DigestValue>VYRVoWOIiZx/7QMavLyDmAZ3Mb0=</ds:DigestValue>
```

The references URI is the message Body:

```
<soapenv:Body xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="Id-4889213">
<web:consultarEstados xmlns:web="https://webservice.face.gob.es"/>
```

If I 'canononicalize' this manualy, and try and apli sha1, the result I get is exactly the DigestValue.

Hand canonicalized soapenv:Body:

```
<soapenv:Body xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="Id-4889213"><web:consultarEstados xmlns:web="https://webservice.face.gob.es"></web:consultarEstados></soapenv:Body>
```

Command to generate sh1 value: (store in bodyib.txt previos string with can. body)

```
cat bodyib.txt|openssl dgst -binary -sha1 | openssl enc -base64
```

output:

```
VYRVoWOIiZx/7QMavLyDmAZ3Mb0= (Yes, the value in DigestValue !!)
```

When I sign my message, i get the following Reference:

```
<ds:Reference URI="#Id-4889213">
<ds:Transforms>
    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
    <InclusiveNamespaces xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList=""/>
    </ds:Transform>
    </ds:Transforms>
    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
    <ds:DigestValue>sA5MIQPm4b2YhMRTPHg9CY8J1FI=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
```

I mimic all namespace and Id to get exactly the same soap message as the example I have. So I get the foolowing soapenv:Body:

```
<soapenv:Body xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="Id-4889213">
```

If I canonicalize this by hand, I get exactly the same string as earlier but the DigestValue shown in Reference is not the same.

I have tried this with two different jsr105 providers:

Oracle:                     "org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.XMLDSigRI"
Apcher santuario (1.5.6) :  "org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.XMLDSigRI"

And the result is the same Digest (different to the one I expect based on the example I have). I don't where these digest is coming from. When I try to calculate this by hand, the result is the one in the example.

I imagine I don't get some concept of this all thing, because using two different libraries I get the same value, so I don't thing problem is the code of this libraries.

Answer (score 2):

I found what the difference is in the data that is going to be sign. The problem is related to http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n# transform Algorithm. I don't know witch one is correct:

The contente that is being sign in my example:

```
<soapenv:Body xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="Id-4889213"><web:consultarEstados></web:consultarEstados></soapenv:Body>
```

I don't know why

```
<web:consultarEstados></web:consultarEstados>
```

doesn't have namespace information.

This could be a bug in org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.XMLDSigRI implementation of http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#, may be when element is empty.

I will try to find out.

Found problem finally:
Before signing I am doing some namespace changes, tryint to macht example I have. I have to add:
**soapEnvelope.getOwnerDocument().normalizeDocument();**

For the canonicalization to work properly. Without this, canonicalization doesn't work right.